# Nested foreach loops on a json object not returning correct values and structure

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I can't figure out why my array loop isn't working.

I'm trying to loop on a decoded JSON object

```
+"categoryCode": "1122"
+"category_description": "This is the category Description"
+"products": array:24 [▼
  0 => {#999 ▼
    +"pricing": {#1011 ▼
      +"MainPrice": "40.00"
    }
    +"productInfo": {#1009 ▼
      +"product": {#1014 ▼
        +"product_type": {#1015 ▼
          +"desc": "Test Product"
          +"quantDetails": 3.0
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And build a new `$priceResult` array out of the values that I need. I want the category info on the first level of the array and then follow with product info.

WHy isn't this loop building my new array properly? When I dump $priceResult, I get the category info, but then I just get the price and a bunch of null values on the same level. Am I looping and building the new array incorrectly?

```
$priceResult = array();

foreach($pricing->categories as $category){ 

    $priceResult[] = $category->categoryCode;
    $priceResult[] = $category->category_description;

    foreach($category->products as $product){

        foreach ($product->pricing as $price => $amount) {

            $priceResult[] = $amount;

        }

        foreach($product->productInfo as $info){

            foreach($info->product as $product){

                foreach($product->product_type as $type){

                    $priceResult[] = $type->desc;
                    $priceResult[] = $type->quantDetails;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update with output:

Here's an example of some erroneous output

```
      0 => "CategoryOne"
  1 => "1122"
  2 => "This is the category Description"
  3 => null
  4 => null
  5 => null
  6 => null
  7 => null
  8 => null
  9 => null
  10 => null
  11 => null
  12 => null
  13 => null
  14 => null
  15 => null
  16 => null
  17 => null
  18 => null
  19 => "40.00"
  20 => null
  21 => null
  22 => null
  23 => null
  24 => null
  25 => null
  26 => null
  27 => null
  28 => null
  29 => null
  30 => null
  31 => null
  32 => null
  33 => null
  34 => null
  35 => null
  36 => "50.00"
```

Update with desired output:

```
CategoryName : TestCategory
CategoryDescription: For Testing
    Products{
        0{
            Product_code : 123,
            CountNumber : 12,
            ProductDescription: Test Product,
            price_amount : 150.00
        },
        1{
            Product_code : 112,
            CountNumber : 32,
            ProductDescription: Test Product 2,
            price_amount : 250.00
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show output ?

Comment: `$product->pricing` is an object, not an array.

Comment: How do you go from `json` to `$pricing->categories` or can you show the actual value of `$pricing->categories` (preferably with `var_export()`)

Comment: You are just pushing everything in the array at the same level with `$priceResult[] = something`. What is your expected result structure?

Comment: @Barmar so I'm looping wrong at that level? Pricing and product_info are on the same level but I need info from each attached as one data set for the category

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I think `$pricing->categories` is the data shown at the top of the question.

Comment: @Barmar - I get that, but I have to make assumptions about `json_decode` without knowing what the data actually is.  (which is ok), but I wouldn't mind seeing the data in an actual PHP structure ... lol

Comment: @Aioros I updated with something along the lines of what I want

Comment: @TomN. The question says you want everything in the top level of the array, not nested like your edit.

Comment: You're using `$priceResult[]` which doesn't create an associative array.

Comment: @Barmar this got me a good bit and I changed it a bit more to fit what I need but can you maybe help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244168/laravel-excel-not-exporting-in-correct-format?noredirect=1#comment95315360_54244168

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel or phpExcel, so I'm not sure if I can be much help with that quesiton.

Comment: @Barmar ah I understand, I wasn't sure if my issue was with the package or the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$product->pricing` and `$product->productInfo` are single objects, not arrays of objects. If you want to loop over the properties of an object, you can use `get_object_vars()` to return an associative array.

```
foreach($pricing->categories as $category){ 

    $priceResult[] = $category->categoryCode;
    $priceResult[] = $category->category_description;

    foreach($category->products as $product){
        foreach (get_object_vars($product->pricing) as $amount) {
            $priceResult[] = $amount;
        }
        foreach (get_object_vars($product->productInfo) as $info) {
            $priceResult[] = $info->desc;
            $priceResult[] = $info->quantDetails;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this works but I have one question: Sometimes pricing has multiple things like ```"Main Price" : "120.00", "secondPrice" : "150.00"```. Is there a way with this object to do similar to what I did above and just tie Price : Amount

Comment: Things would be easier if you use the `TRUE` second argument to `json_decode()`. Then you'll get an associative array and you can loop over that.

Comment: This is laravel, so it decodes it by default. when I try to decode it, it treats it as already decoded and just gives me a null result

Comment: Is there a way to map it like that in the existing structure though?

Comment: You can use `get_object_vars()` to convert an object to an associative array. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I went with `$priceResult` being an array, containing category objects. I think it would look something like this:

```
$priceResult = array()

foreach($pricing->categories as $category){ 
    $c = new stdClass();
    $c->CategoryCode = $category->categoryCode;
    $c->CategoryDescription = $category->category_description;
    $c->Products = array();

    foreach($category->products as $product){
        $p = new stdClass();
        $p->ProductCode = null; // $product->something? no idea where this is
        $p->CountNumber = $product->productInfo->product->product_type->quantDetails;
        $p->ProductDescription = $product->productInfo->product->product_type->desc;
        $p->PriceAmount = $product->pricing->MainPrice;
        $c->Products[] = $p;
    }
    $priceResult[] = $c;
}
```

I do have to say, though, the original data seems to have a very weird structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$categoryArray = [];

foreach($pricing->categories as $category) { 
    $categoryResult['categoryCode'] = $category->categoryCode;
    $categoryResult['CategoryDescription'] = $category->category_description;
    $categoryResult['Products'] = [];
    foreach($category->products as $product) {
        $productResult['Product_code'] = ''; // this doesn't appear in your JSON...
        $productResult['CountNumber'] = $product->productInfo->productType->quantDetails;
        $productResult['ProductDescription'] = $product->productInfo->productType->desc;
        $productResult['price_amount'] = $product->pricing->MainPrice;
        $categoryResult['Products'][] = $productResult;
    }
    $categoryArray[] = $categoryResult;
}

$priceResult = $categoryArray; // ($priceResult is a strange name for this array...)
```

Comment: Would there be a way on price to map the key to the value rather than just using MainPrice? If there were 3 types and I didn't know what they were I would just want all 3 price amounts